# How do JSP custom tag libs from external libraries work?

Tags: jsp, taglib

If you have programmed a custom JSP tag library you should know that you may reference either a URI declared in the web.xml tab-lib element, or reference directly the tld file inside your webapp.

However, when I use an existing taglib such as DisplayTag that is packaged in a jar file included in my web app, you just use the URI. So my question is, how does the container know where to locate the custom tag classes?

Comment: Inside the META-INF of the jar file , there must be a TLD file . [Read here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/taglib/admin.html#wp364493) .

Comment: @TheNewIdiot yes, and in fact, if you uncompress the contents of displaytag-1.2.jar (since this is the jar OP uses as example) you will find the TLD files inside the META-INF folder.

Comment: Does that means that the Servlet Container will look for it at deployment time for every jar in the WEB-INF\lib?

Comment: @andres_farias yes, it will.

Comment: I removed the `[jstl]` tag from the question. JSTL != "custom JSP taglib". See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info